# Executing windows command in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm running Jenkins as Windows service on my PC. I'm trying to learn to use it. For a dummy job, one of the build step is **Execute Windows batch command** with the following command

```
JLink -ip 10.12.1.234
```

When I build the job on Jenkins I get a build error saying **JLink is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.** When I run the command from a command prompt, it runs without any problem. Windows path has been set to the path where JLink is installed. Should I be configure anything additionally in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the fully qualified path (or an environment variable) of the command in Configure Project. Your user must be different from jenkins service, which runs as system

Comment: Yes you are right. It worked when i included the full path. Thank you